# Repairing a corrupt postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

This is what happens when postgresql tries to start after a power failure:

```
2012-01-27 18:00:44 MSK LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2012-01-27 18:00:16 MSK
2012-01-27 18:00:44 MSK HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
2012-01-27 18:00:44 MSK LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2012-01-27 18:00:44 MSK LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 17/762C39B8
2012-01-27 18:00:44 MSK LOG:  redo starts at 17/761F6A40
2012-01-27 18:00:44 MSK FATAL:  invalid page header in block 311757 of relation base/26976/27977
2012-01-27 18:00:44 MSK CONTEXT:  xlog redo insert: rel 1663/26976/27977; tid 311757/44
2012-01-27 18:00:44 MSK LOG:  startup process (PID 392) exited with exit code 1
2012-01-27 18:00:44 MSK LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

I **know** I'm not out of luck and there is a command I can use to repair the database in this situation. It doesn't matter if the last few hours of transactions disappear, as long as the database becomes consistent.

Please advice me on what to do in this situation.

Comment: Belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how much you're willing to give up on data side.

You can set `zero_damaged_pages` to on in your postgresql.conf configuration file and then give it a try - but that **will** cause data loss. It might work or might not work.

If you want to try that, **always** start by shutting down the postgres database and taking a full filesystem copy of it (e.g. tar). Because it might still be the least broken version you have. Then once you've set it, run a `pg_dump` right away, wipe the cluster, and restore the dump. And absolutely do not run the new cluster with `zero_damaged_pages` on by default, remember to turn it back off!

And then set up proper Point-In-Time Recovery backups for the new cluster.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it using below commands:

```
mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql/9.6-main.pg_stat_tmp

sudo service postgresql-9.6 restart
```

change filename/versions as shown in error message.

Comment: Thank you! I already thought that everything would be lost.

Comment: This worked for me! Before your mkdir command, I ran sudo rm -r /var/run/postgresql/(version)-main.pg_stat_tmp to delete the corrupted temp files.

Answer (score 1):

Restore from the last backup, then reapply the logs from there.

Unless you have the last backup and all logs since then, you're screwed.

Comment: I dont have a backup, but I know it's possible to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the following error:

```
LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/ui6h1i/PG_13_202007201/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/ui6h1i/PG_13_202007201": Not a directory
```

It turned out that `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_tblspc/ui6h1i` was actually an executable instead of a directory. I made a backup of the data folder, then deleted `ui6h1i`. Postgres was then able to start up, and seems to be working.

(using postgres 13)